# Accessing UI component on Activity from the Service class's Thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-activity

I've a class named by MyService which extends Service below. Everything will be ran until 
I remove the `Toast.makeText...` line in the run method of Thread.

**Why? And how can I get access to the Activity components from the run method of Thread class?**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return null; }

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "This msg will be shown", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("Bilgi", "This msg will be shown.");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "This msg will be shown", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.d("This msg will ","be shown"); //if I remove next line 
                Toast.makeText(this, "This msg will NOT be shown", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, 5000, 8000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And how can I get access to the Activity components from the run method of Thread class?

You don't. Use `Messenger` to send `Message` objects from the service to the activity's `Handler`. The activity -- and only the activity -- can update its widgets, and that only from the main application thread.

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/Downloader) demonstrating this.

Comment: Could one also use a bound service by [extending the binder class](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder)? The Android documentation seems to suggest this approach over using `Messenger` when "your service is merely a background worker for your own application."

Comment: @AST: That would be another option, as would an event bus.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use Threads](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) - use [AyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  Also, you shouldn't be accessing the Activity methods/UI through threads/tasks.  Take a look at the first link to get an idea of how the Activity and its "threads" work together.

Comment: AsyncTasks are now deprecated: This class was deprecated in API level 30.
Use the standard java.util.concurrent or Kotlin concurrency utilities instead.

Answer (score 0):

The only method I know is to use broadcast receiver inside your activity, which will catch you messages and update UI or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the Toast, pass in the ApplicationContext which you can get through getApplicationContext()

Comment: Do you mean, pass context to MyService from Activity and pass context.getApplicationContext() to Toast.makeText() method as a parameter like `Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "textextexte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` ?

Comment: No, as Service is an extension of Context, you could just call getApplicationContext() within the Service; Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()..

Comment: inside OnStart method of MyService class, first Toast.makeText method is working but `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try { Toast.makeText.......
`

Answer (score 0):

**The UI widgets are not thread-safe** so you can not update the the UI widget unless in the Main(UI) Thread , in your case, making `Toast` is in another thread which is forbidden.

You may need to use something like `Handler`, and use `Messenger` to send message to the handler created in the activity UI thread. And then deal with the widgets in method `handleMessage(Message msg)`.